# Spring boot with firebird database null data

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, firebird

Пробую делать REST сервис на Spring Boot + Firebird 3.0.4, получаю пустые данные [{},{},{},{},{}]
количество строк верное, подскажите куда копать

AppTest

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppTest {

@GetMapping
public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello!";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AppTest.class, args);
}
}
```

Customer

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS7")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

private Integer id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private String gender;
}
```

CustomerController

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/req")

public class CustomerController {
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository repo;

@GetMapping
public Iterable<Customer> getAllCustomer(){
  return repo.findAll();
}
}
```

CustomerRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, 
Integer> {

}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=7777
spring.datasource.driverClassName:org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/D:\\
spring.datasource.username:SYSDBA
spring.datasource.password:***
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=windows-1251
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:none
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.http.encoding.charset=windows-1251
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

DDL

```
SET SQL DIALECT 3;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS7 (
ID       INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
NAME     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
EMAIL    VARCHAR(50),
PHONE    VARCHAR(50),
GENDER   VARCHAR(50),
CITY     VARCHAR(50),
STATE    VARCHAR(50),
COUNTRY  VARCHAR(50)
);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS7 ALTER ID RESTART WITH 0;

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS7 ADD UNIQUE (EMAIL);
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS7 ADD UNIQUE (PHONE);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS7 ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Comment: данные в БД есть? репо их находит?

Comment: данные есть, количество итераций соответствует количеству записей, по repo пытаюсь найти что там происходит

Comment: c h2 database все работает, я думаю здесь проблема в firebird и @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Comment: определите нормально геттеры и сеттры, equals и hachCode, затем пустой конструктор в классе-сущности. Откажитесь от lombok